# Making geolocated latitude/longitude values available to computed field in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, location, entities

I'm working on a D7 project where I need to pass a latitude/longitude value from a Location field (acquired from geolocating during import) to a Computed field.

I found the following code in the computed field documentation, which loads the field into the computed field:

`$field_info = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_geo'));`

However, if I do a `dpm($field_info);` all location information is there, *EXCEPT* lat/long.

Any way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was assuming locations are geolocated on edit/changes and that's saved to DB, which appears to not be the case. At any rate, I was able to use the location ID from $field_info to load the location, which then has the lat/long data I need:

```
$loc = location_load_location($field_info['lid']);
$longitude = $loc['longitude'];
$latitude = $loc['latitude'];
```

That was annoying...

Comment: My content has field_latitude and field_longitude. How would I grab those in the PHP field of the location filter? Or at least, how can I dpm() SOMETHING in there to help me find it? there's no $view, $vars, $variables, etc. And there's certainly no documentation on getting fields from your nodes in there.