# Computed field with latitude/longitude

Tags: location, entities

I made node with location field (track) and computed field. I want to measure distance between two points. In computed field is:

**Computed Code (PHP) :**

```
$longitude1= $entity->field_track[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['longitude'];
$longitude2 =  $entity->field_track[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['longitude'];
$latitude1 = $entity->field_track[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['latitude'];
$latitude2 = $entity->field_track[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['latitude'];

$entity_field[0]['value'] = earth_distance($longitude1, $latitude1, $longitude2, $latitude2);
```

**Display Code (PHP):**

```
$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];
```

I think, I am stucked in reading field_track[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['longitude']; Can anyone help me how to read longitude an latitude to earth distance formula? Thank you.

Comment: what do you get when you do a `dsm()` or other such variable print or dump of `$entity->field_track`?

Comment: I am too much lama to answer your question Jimajamma.

Comment: If you put `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($entity->field_track, TRUE) . '</pre>');` in there, what does it print out?

Comment: Now I am trying this code:

`$field_info = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_trat'));

$loc = location_load_location($field_info['lid']);
$longitude = $loc['longitude'];
$latitude = $loc['latitude'];

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $longitude;
$entity_field[1]['value'] = $latitude;`

But I get only one position and I want to count with lets say 5 positions in formula earth distance.

Thank you @Jimajamma

Comment: Array
(
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lid] => 180
                    [name] => 
                    [street] => 
                    [additional] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [province] => 
                    [postal_code] => 
                    [country] => cz
                    [latitude] => 49.877933
                    [longitude] => 13.886719
too long to send the rest... :(

Comment: You are adding to the question here but you can see that the `longitude` is in there, so it is looking to be a basic php coding question, and not a drupal one.  IMHO.

Comment: Ok, I understand, so can you finish your answer, please?

Comment: this is a php not a drupal question

Comment: $entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_trat['und'][0]['lid'];
this is working
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_trat['und'][0]['longitude'];
this not

Comment: according this post... [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34584/making-geolocated-latitude-longitude-values-available-to-computed-field-in-drupa]  .. i think you are not right